# how to compare two vectors index by index contained by shared_ptr

Tags: c++, for-loop, shared-ptr

I have a two shared pointers to vector of strings:
`b_paras` and `b_paras_sig`

I have traversed the loop for each, using range based `for` loop as follows:

```
for ( const std::string &para1 : *b_paras )
```

and

```
for ( const std::string &para2 : *b_paras_sig)
```

**Now I want to compare the each element of these vectors, index by index and find out the mismatch.**

I think nested loop may not fit as a solution here.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`std::mismatch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no elegant way to do that in C++, AFAIK.
Python has a handful zip() function to iterate over multiple sequences at once, and Boost has an equivalent: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html

Otherwise just make something like

```
    for(auto it = std::make_pair(a->begin(), b->begin()); 
        it.first != a->end() && it.second != b->end();
        ++it.first, ++it.second) {
            if (*it.first != *it.second) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```